# Why is my objects key, value pair being overridden instead of creating a new key, value pair?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create an object of objects within an object with dynamically created key,value pairs, but the nested object keeps overriding the key value pair instead of creating a new key value pair.

```
ObjectIDWithQuestions = {};
var ArrayOfBlocks1 = [
  {
    ID: "block1",
    block: "block1",
    BlockElements: [
      { QuestionID: "1"  },
      { QuestionID: "2"  }
    ]
  },
  {
    ID: "block2",
    block: "block2",
    BlockElements: [
      {  QuestionID: "1"  },
      {  QuestionID: "2"  }
    ]
  },
  {
    ID: "block3",
    block: "block3",
    BlockElements: [
      {  QuestionID: "1"  },
      {  QuestionID: "2"  }
    ]
      }
];

for(i=0;i<ArrayOfBlocks1.length;i++){
    for(k=0;k<ArrayOfBlocks1[i].BlockElements.length;k++){
        var ArrayOfBlocks2 = ArrayOfBlocks1[i].ID
        ObjectIDWithQuestions[ArrayOfBlocks2]={}
        ObjectIDWithQuestions[""+ArrayOfBlocks2]["questions"+ k]=ArrayOfBlocks1[i].BlockElements[k].QuestionID

    }
}
console.log(ObjectIDWithQuestions);
```

The expected result of the code is to create an object that is an object of objects that has a two dynamically created key, value pairs instead of one key, value pair that is being overridden.for example, the following code prints:

```
block1: {questions1: "2"}
block2: {questions1: "2"}
block3: {questions1: "2"}
```

When it should print

```
block1: {questions0: "1",questions1:"2"}
block2: {questions0: "1",questions1:"2"}
block3: {questions0: "1",questions1:"2"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize

```
var ArrayOfBlocks2 = ArrayOfBlocks1[i].ID
ObjectIDWithQuestions[ArrayOfBlocks2]={}
```

outside the inner loop. Otherwise it will create an object every time the inner loop iterates

```js
ObjectIDWithQuestions = {};
var ArrayOfBlocks1 = [
  {
    ID: "block1",
    block: "block1",
    BlockElements: [
      { QuestionID: "1"  },
      { QuestionID: "2"  }
    ]
  },
  {
    ID: "block2",
    block: "block2",
    BlockElements: [
      {  QuestionID: "1"  },
      {  QuestionID: "2"  }
    ]
  },
  {
    ID: "block3",
    block: "block3",
    BlockElements: [
      {  QuestionID: "1"  },
      {  QuestionID: "2"  }
    ]
      }
];

for(i=0;i<ArrayOfBlocks1.length;i++){
     var ArrayOfBlocks2 = ArrayOfBlocks1[i].ID
     ObjectIDWithQuestions[ArrayOfBlocks2]={}
     for(k=0;k<ArrayOfBlocks1[i].BlockElements.length;k++){  
        ObjectIDWithQuestions[""+ArrayOfBlocks2]["questions"+ k]=ArrayOfBlocks1[i].BlockElements[k].QuestionID

     }
}
console.log(ObjectIDWithQuestions);
```

Comment: Oh my heck thank you! I have been trying to figure this out forever!

Comment: I'll accept your answer in 2 minutes when it allows me to :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two lines from inner loop and move it to outside of the inner loop,

```
ArrayOfBlocks2 = ArrayOfBlocks1[i].ID
ObjectIDWithQuestions[ArrayOfBlocks2] = {}
```

This should do the trick